# Scrolling HTML data with angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to repeat list having `html` data with angular.js.
And I want to use `ngInfiniteScroll`.

So I have built a template, like this.

update:

```
<div class="scroll" id="antTalkList" talk-type="total" view-type="total"
    infinite-scroll='$ctrl.loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2'>
    <ul class="user_list list ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.htmlViews">
        <ng-bind-html ng-bind-html="item"> </ng-bind-html>
</ul>
</div>
```

As you can see above, I don't know how to repeat `$ctrl.htmlViews` inside `ul`. each htmlViews's item is filled with HTML data above.

`<li ... > ... </li> ... <li ... > ... </li>`

This is my `antList` component. In controller, `htmlViews` is pushed by ajax call when the controller is initialized and scrolled(loadMore function).

`ng-repeat` seems okay, maybe It works well. However, the `infinite-scroll` is not working. I added `infinite-scroll="$ctrl.loadMore()"` and `infinite-scroll-distance='10'`.

LoadMore function is called when initialized, but it doesn't called when I'm scrolling. How can I check this case?

Here is my component snippets.

```
.component('antList', {
    templateUrl : 'templates/ant-list.html'
    , controller : function AntListController($http, $attrs, $sce){
        var self = this;
        this.htmlViews = [];
        this.loading = false;

        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "ant/list?sectionId="+$attrs.talkType+"&pageCount=20&startIndex=0"
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            self.htmlViews.push($sce.trustAsHtml(response.data));
        });

        this.loadMore = function(){
            $http({
                method : "GET",
                url : 'ant/list?pageCount=20&startIndex=' 
                    + $('#antTalkList .user_list li').size()
                    + '&sectionId=' +$attrs.talkType
            }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                self.htmlViews.push($sce.trustAsHtml(response.data));
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: You should use `$comple` for compile your template.

Comment: @gianlucatursi Hmm, I found it. Maybe I'm a stupid, ng-repeat needs in ul tags. No problems on template. I'll update with another content.

Comment: ops. i'm sorry. I didn't understand the question. i think the solution below is correct.

Comment: @gianlucatursi Nevermind :), Is that okay what I change my question?

Comment: Actually, loading data when I scrolled is not working well, this is a real problem.

Comment: I think you should have `infinite-scroll` in `<ul>` tag and a `<ng-bind-html ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.htmlVies" ng-bind-html="item"></ng-bind-html>`. You have a div that contain the ul. (i think.. you can try)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="scroll" id="antTalkList" talk-type="total" view-type="total"
    infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2'>
    <ul class="user_list list ng-scope">
        <li ng-repeat="view in htmlViews">
         {{view}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank yo so much. You're so fast but I should update my question. :(